# Pass a LogRecordSet into a method

Tags: c#, logparser

I have a small command line app written in C# that uses LogParser and I was looking to clean it up a little because it is all in one massive method.

I run my query and I get a LogRecordSet object:

```
// run the query against wowza log
LogRecordSet logSet = logQuery.Execute(sql, new W3CInputFormat());
```

All good. Now I want to pass logSet into a method where I will evaluate everything:

```
private static IEnumerable<Unprocessed> CreateRecords(LogRecordSet logRecordset)
{
    for (; !logRecordset.atEnd(); logRecordset.moveNext())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I call it like so:

```
var records = CreateRecords(logSet);
```

This compiles fine, however it just sort of ignores the CreateRecords method, just skips over it. I admittedly know very little about c# command line applications, but I would just be interested to know why this is happening, and wasn't really sure what to google.

**Edit**
I have looked into a little more, and the problem seems to stem from the fact that my method uses

```
yield return log;
```

Can I not use yield return in this context?

```
private static IEnumerable<Unprocessed> CreateRecords(LogRecordSet logRecordset)
{
    for (; !logRecordset.atEnd(); logRecordset.moveNext())
    {
        yield return ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CreateRecords()` looks ok, just make sure you start enumerating its returned IEnumerable and you'll see it'll get invoked. For example:

```
var foo = CreateRecords().ToArray();
```

Comment: Aha, excellent, thanks. Goddamn ienumerables, really need to get my head around them